# data exchange using socket between Julia and Groovy

Tags: sockets, groovy, io, julia

Recently I'm trying to use a socket to exchange data between a solver in Julia as a server and a client in Groovy. Im new to the socket concept and both the language. The thing is that  it seems that once julia server done 'readLine()', the socket close and the 'write()' cannot proceed. I cannot send messages to the Groovy client nor exchange data.

Server code(Julia):

```
using Sockets

server = listen(2000)
while true
  conn = accept(server)
  println("connection accepted")
  @async begin
    try
        line = readlines(conn)
        println(line)
        str = "server"
        write(conn,str)
        println("write done")
        sleep(2)

        
    catch err
      print("connection ended with error $err")
      sleep(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Client code(Groovy):

```
class groovy_client {

    static void main(String[] args) {


        while (true) {
            try {
                dataTransfer()
                println 'dataTransfer success'
            }catch (e) {
                println(e)
                sleep(2000)
            }


        }




    }

    private static void dataTransfer() {
        Socket s = new Socket('localhost', 2000)
        println 'connect to the server'
        s.withStreams { input, output ->


            // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
            // str = reader.readLine()
            // println(str)

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output))
            writer.write('Hi server')
            writer.flush()

            input.withReader{reader ->
                str = reader.readLine()
                println 'haha'
                println(str)

            // def reader = input.newReader()
            // def buffer = reader.readLine()
            // println "server: $buffer"
            sleep(2000)
            }
        println 'disconnect'
        }


    }
}
```

And I also have a doubt about how the socket works. Do server and client send and receive messages at the same time? Like server tells the client to add 1 to int_a while client send int_a back to the sender. Does int_a remain the original value or with 1 added and sent to the server?

Comment: 1st problem - readLine requires other side to write new line symbol. 2nd - better to design communication flow - for example client asks- server replies.

Comment: Hi daggett, thank you for the reply. About the first question, I have client write in the buffer already. But somehow it seems the program stuck at some point before 'readline'.   And about the second, do y ou mean only do one thing at each connection?

Comment: first is not a question - it's a problem in your code that will block communication.

Comment: Ya you are right. I forgot the '\n' so the readLine() kept blocking the communication.